# How do I combine these two queries using Union?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two queries that I am trying to combine into one using a union statement.

This is what I have so far:

```
    (Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor',
        sum(a.amount) as 'Total Paid', 0 as Pocket 
        From Donor d, Pledge p, Payment a
        Where d.DonorId=p.DonorId
        and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
        group by d.donorid)

        union all

    (Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor',
        0 as 'Total Paid',sum(a.amount) as 'Pocket'
        From Donor d, Pledge p, Payment a
        Where (a.CompanyId is null) 
        and d.DonorId=p.DonorId
        and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
        group by d.donorid);
```

This creates:

```
+--------------+------------+---------+
| Donor        | Total Paid | Pocket  |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| John Smith   |    3500.00 |    0.00 |
| Linda Smith  |     250.00 |    0.00 |
| Jack Clinton |     200.00 |    0.00 |
| Jane Doe     |    2100.00 |    0.00 |
| John Smith   |       0.00 | 1750.00 |
| Linda Smith  |       0.00 |  100.00 |
| Jack Clinton |       0.00 |  200.00 |
| Jane Doe     |       0.00 | 2100.00 |
+--------------+------------+---------+
```

I don't know how to get rid of the repeating sections.  I want the top four names to be combined with the bottom four names to create 4 names with both "total paid" and "pocket" to have values and not zeros.

Just to be clear, I want the output to look like this:

```
+--------------+------------+---------+
| Donor        | Total Paid | Pocket  |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| John Smith   |    3500.00 | 1750.00 |
| Linda Smith  |     250.00 |  100.00 |
| Jack Clinton |     200.00 |  200.00 |
| Jane Doe     |    2100.00 | 2100.00 |
+--------------+------------+---------+
```

I know I am missing something about the union statement, I just don't know what it is.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't have to, you can just calculate conditional `sum` (with `case`):

```
select concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor'
     , sum(a.amount) as 'Total Paid'
     , sum(case when a.CompanyId is null then a.amount else 0 end) as 'Pocket' 
from Donor d
join Pledge p on d.DonorId = p.DonorId
join Payment a on p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
group by d.donorid
```

Comment: This returns a syntax error at line 5.  I am not very familiar with the case statement or the way you have used join, so I am having trouble figuring out what the sytax error is.

Comment: I should have caught that.  Thanks a lot.  This is exactly what I was looking for.